# Alternative to NOT IN?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to check two tables and find inconsistencies, ie where the value of table T1 is not present in the italy_cities table. I'll explain:

T1: Includes personal data (with place of birth)
italy_city: Includes all the municipalities of Italy.

Table T1 has about 9000 tuples.
T2 has 7,903 tuples.

Using "NOT IN" the query takes approximately 16 seconds to execute.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    `T1`.* 
FROM
    T1
WHERE
    (
    `T1`.place NOT IN ( SELECT municipality FROM italy_cities ) 
    )
```

**MY QUESTION** 
what is the best and fast option to check for inconsistencies? to check all the "incorrect" municipalities that do not exist in the official database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Typically EXISTS/NOT EXISTS is the best for checking inconsistencies if you don't need to actually return the data.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, and the execution plan for that query

Comment: Provided municipality is not nullable, `NOT IN` should lead to the same execution plan as `NOT EXISTS` or an anti join. At least this is what I expect from more recent MySQL versions. If your MySQL version is very old, this may not be the case, though. You'll want an index on `t1(place)` for either of these queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally recommend `NOT EXISTS` for this purpose:

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM italy_cities ic
                  WHERE t1.place = ic.municipality
                 );
```

Why?  There are two reasons:

1. `NOT IN` does not do what you expect if the subquery returns *any* `NULL` values.  If even one value is `NULL` all rows end up being filtered out.
2. This version of the query can take advantage of an index on `italy_cities(municipality)` which seems like a reasonable index on the table.

Answer (score 1):

`Not exists` can perform better but there is also another way which is `left join` as follows:

```
SELECT T1.* 
  FROM T1
  LEFT JOIN italy_cities I ON I.municipality = T1.PLACE
 WHERE I.municipality IS NULL;
```